# MediaPipe segmentation mask for Pose Detection Web

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mediapipe

Following the MediaPipe Pose landmark detection guide for the web (that you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/pose_landmarker/web_js)) I managed to correctly display and overlay the resulting landamarks on a video. But I am struggling to display the segmentation mask (which should be possible according to this [demo](https://mediapipe-studio.webapps.google.com/studio/demo/pose_landmarker).

After setting the option `outputSegmentationMasks` to `true`, I run the Task using `PoseLandmarker.detectedVideo()`. The attribute `segmentationMasks` is available and returns a list of *poses* (I guess), and `result[0].canvas` is an instance of `OffscreenCanvas`.

I was hoping to draw the resulting mask using

```js
// rendering loop
canvasCtxVideo.save();
canvasCtxVideo.clearRect(0, 0, canvasCamera.clientWidth, canvasCamera.height);
canvasCtxVideo.drawImage(
    result.segmentationMasks[0].canvas,
    0,
    0,
    canvasCamera.clientWidth,
    canvasCamera.height
);
canvasCtxVideo.restore();
```

but nothing is shown on the `HTMLCanvas`.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**:

Since `result[0].canvas` is an `OffsetCanvas` I started looking into the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas). This article suggests that you can either use a `WebWorker`, or convert the canvas to a an `ÌmageBitmap` using the method `OffsetBuffer.transferToImageBitmap()`.

Unfortunately neither solution works, because:

1. it is not possible to transfer an `OffsetCanvas` to a `WebWorker` if it already has a rendering context.
2. with the following snippet the canvas remains blank:

```
const maskCanvas = document.getElementById("mask_canvas")
const maskCanvasCtx = maskCanvas.getContext("bitmaprenderer")

const mask = result.segmentationMasks[0]
const image = mask.canvas.transferToImageBitmap()
maskCanvasCtx.transferFromImageBitmap(image)
```

Comment: Can't you use the segmentation demo as an example? https://codepen.io/mediapipe-preview/pen/xxJNjbN?editors=0010